# spark- scala:How to read data from .dat file transform it and finally store in HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark- scala so pls help me. I have .dat file which contains list of data as given bellow which has serial no,firstname,lastnsme .File has 19000 records:

SerialNo FirstName LastName

1        Jhon      Ward

2         Jasper   Pinto

3         Shally    Stun

.etc

1. I need to **read data from that .dat file in Spark RDD**.
2. Transform it **to get the RDD data sorted by first name** and finally **store the sorted data in HDFS** with below specifications:

   - Output file should only **have first name and last name**
   - first name and last name should be **delimited by " %$ " signs**
   - Output should be **stored in a single file**.
3. **Finally store in HDFS**

I am not sure how to write code for this in spark-scala .so pls help me with this.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), [idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the solution

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path/Test.dat")
val rddmap = rdd.map(i => i.split(" ")).map(i => (i(1),i(2))).sortByKey().map(i => i._1 + "%$" + i._2)
rddmap.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/path/TestOut1.dat")
```

output

Jasper%$Pinto

Jhon%$Ward

Shally%$Stun

Comment: Could fuse two `map`s into one: `.map(i => { val a = i.split(" "); (a(1), a(2)) })`.