# How to read first record from .dat file transform it and finally store in HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a .dat file in aws s3 using spark scala shell, and create a new file with just the first record of the .dat file.

Let's say my file path to the .dat file is "s3a://filepath.dat"

I assume my logic should look something like but I wasn't able to figure out how to get the first record.

```
val file = sc.textFile("s3a://filepath.dat")
val onerecord = file.getFirstRecord()
onerecord.saveAsTextFile("s3a://newfilepath.dat")
```

I've been trying to follow these solutions

[How to skip first and last line from a dat file and make it to dataframe using scala in databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987228/how-to-skip-first-and-last-line-from-a-dat-file-and-make-it-to-dataframe-using-s)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809228/spark-scalahow-to-read-data-from-dat-file-transform-it-and-finally-store-in-h#:~:text=dat%20file%20in%20Spark%20RDD,be%20delimited%20by%20%22%20%25%24%20%22%20signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809228/spark-scalahow-to-read-data-from-dat-file-transform-it-and-finally-store-in-h#:%7E:text=dat%20file%20in%20Spark%20RDD,be%20delimited%20by%20%22%20%25%24%20%22%20signs)

Comment: For RDD function "zipWithIndex()" can be used, and filtered for index==1, or function "first()" and new RDD can be created for this one value.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use `spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).option("delimiter", "|").load("s3a://filepath.dat")`
and then `res4.limit(1)` and finally 
`res5.rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile("./newfile.dat")`
However this seems to create a directory named newfile.dat rather than a file of type .dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how records are separated in your .dat file, but in general, you could do something like this(think delimiter is '|'):

```
val raw = session.sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").load("data/input.txt")
val firstItem = raw.first()
```

It looks weird but it will solve your problem.

Comment: I used spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).option("delimiter", "|").load("s3a://filepath.dat") and that worked.

Comment: I ran res4.limit(1)

Comment: and then ran res5.rdd.saveAsTextFile("./newfile.dat") but it seems to have created a directory named newfile.dat rather than a .dat file. I need a .dat file and not a directory.